# Update layout with the animation

Tags: android, animation

I have a custom View inherited from LinearLayout. It contains a Button
and a EditText. EditText has initial visibility set to GONE. When
Button is pressed I want EditText to appear with animation effect. So
I've made an ScaleAnimation and when Button is pressed I set
EditText#setVisibility(VISIBLE) and start the animation. The problem
is that it takes 100% of space and animation is performed inside those
bounds. So when there are more View's placed below they are moved down
immediately, but I want them to move slowly as the animation
progresses. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: could you share your code here? sounds interesting

Answer (score -1):

I've used to solve my issue by overriding applyTransformation method of Animation and call View's setLayoutParams according to transformation.

Comment: could you please post some code of your solution here? I do have the same problem.